# Keep a log of system start with GNU grub2 bootloader?

Tags: logs, grub2, remote

Since the GNU grub2 bootloader is able to read files from partitions and supports ext4 filesystem is there a way to make it record/log boot processes to a file?

Such a log would help me enormously to debug the boot process of a remote system I have no console access.

Given some research I assume this ( https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Environment-block )is the way to go?

Comment: @A.B true, but besides its limited size it is exactly what helps me register a variable to trace some boot stuff remotely (without console access to the system) :)